# The differences between 5 behavioral model for OR gate

Tags: delay, verilog

I want to design 5 behavioral model for `OR` gate. What is the difference between these models? Each of models implement which of delays (inertial delay and transport delay) and what is the reason?

Model 1: LHS blocking

```
#4 O = (A | B);
```

Model 2: LHS non-blocking

```
#4 O <= (A | B);
```

Model 3: RHS blocking

```
O = #4 (A | B);
```

Model 4: RHS non-blocking

```
O <= #4 (A | B);
```

Model 5: Continuous assignment

```
assign #4 O = (A | B);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good paper "[Correct Methods For Adding Delays To Verilog Behavioral Models](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs152/fa06/handouts/CummingsHDLCON1999_BehavioralDelays_Rev1_1.pdf)" by Clifford E. Cummings, where you can find some hints about using different delay models in Verilog:

- Blocking assignment delay models:

  > **Modeling Guideline**: do not place delays on the LHS of
  >   blocking assignments to model combinational logic. This
  >   is a bad coding style.
  >   **Testbench Guideline**: placing delays on the LHS of
  >   blocking assignments in a testbench is reasonable since
  >   the delay is just being used to time-space sequential input
  >   stimulus events.
- RHS blocking delays:

  > **Modeling Guideline**: do not place delays on the RHS of
  >   blocking assignments to model combinational logic. This
  >   is a bad coding style.
  >   **Testbench Guideline**: do not place delays on the RHS of
  >   blocking assignments in a testbench.
  >   **General Guideline**: placing a delay on the RHS of any
  >   blocking assignment is both confusing and a poor coding
  >   style. This Verilog coding practice should be avoided.
- Nonblocking assignment delay models:

  > **Modeling Guideline**: do not place delays on the LHS of
  >   nonblocking assignments to model combinational logic.
  >   This is a bad coding style.
  >   **Testbench Guideline**: nonblocking assignments are less
  >   efficient to simulate than blocking assignments; therefore,
  >   in general, placing delays on the LHS of nonblocking
  >   assignments for either modeling or testbench generation is
  >   discouraged.
- RHS nonblocking delays:

  > **Recommended Application**: Use this coding style to
  >   model behavioral delay-line logic.
  >   **Modeling Guideline**: place delays on the RHS of
  >   nonblocking assignments only when trying to model
  >   transport output-propagation behavior. This coding style
  >   will accurately model delay lines and combinational logic
  >   with pure transport delays; however, this coding style
  >   generally causes slower simulations.
  >   **Testbench Guideline**: This coding style is often used in
  >   testbenches when stimulus must be scheduled on future
  >   clock edges or after a set delay, while not blocking the
  >   assignment of subsequent stimulus events in the same
  >   procedural block.
- Continuous assignment delay models:

  > RHS delay model is illegal with continuous assignment

Models mentioned earlier model following delays:

- Adding delays to continuous assignments accurately models combinational logic with *inertial* delays.
- Adding delays to the right hand side (RHS) of nonblocking assignments will accurately model combinational logic with *transport*
  delays.